# Efficient way to add two lines at the beginning of a very large file

Tags: unix, command-line, sed, text-files

I have a group of very large (a couple of GB's each) text files. I need to add two lines at the beginning of each of these files.

I tried using sed with the following command

```
sed -i '1iFirstLine'
sed -i '2iSecondLine'
```

The problem with sed is that it loops through the entire file, even if had to add only two lines at the beginning and therefore it takes lot of time.

Is there an alternate way to do this more efficiently, without reading the entire file?

Comment: @Nykakin Did you read the question? :-)

Comment: There is a wonderful explanation here [http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/](http://http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/) also describing potential pitfalls of the PEARL approach.

Comment: Your sed command would be faster if you did: `sed -i -e '1iFirstLine' -e '2iSecondLine' -e '3q'`.

Comment: @Thor, this will only print 3 lines in the file. The remaining lines will not get printed.

Comment: You're right, my test was faulty.

Comment: But without the final `-e3q` that's as good as the other fixes. (The second line should also be inserted at line 1, though.)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try

```
echo "1iFirstLine" > newfile.txt
echo "2iSecondLine" >> newfile.txt
cat oldfile.txt >> newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt oldfile.txt
```

Comment: I guess this is going to be slower than what I am doing right now, since it involves cat'ing the old fine and then renaming it. Also it is going to create a new file with the same size.

Comment: Nop it's faster check with the executable time and do a script, example "time /bin/sh script1.sh"

Comment: The answer is as correct as the one using perl; both solutions copy the entire file, this one is just obvious about it.

Comment: You don't need perl ... it's better for embedded devices ;-)

Comment: The rename is negligible and the copying is inevitable. Apart from the ugly temp file, this is no worse than the other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

This one is perfectly working and its extremely fast too.

```
perl -pi -e '$.=0 if eof;print "first line\nsecond line\n" if ($.==1)' *.txt
```

Comment: Wow!! this works and is very fast too. No need to parse through the entire file or create temporary files. I guess it's time that I brush up my perl skills a bit. Thanks.

Comment: This also copies the whole file.

Comment: @Sudar you are wrong. There's no on-the fly magic. It **HAVE TO** create temporary file, like it or no. And for `fast` - maybe it is, but do the test to see if that's true. Simple prepend invocation with `time` and see how long it takes

Comment: Damn! May be I spoke too soon. This perl command adds the new lines for every line present in the file :(

Comment: On large files, you can let the command run and then do Ctrl+C immediately and the first line will still be written to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Adding at the beginning is not possible without file rewrite (contrary to appending to the end). You simply cannot "shift" file content as no filesystem supports that. So you should do:

```
echo -e "line 1\nLine2" > tmp.txt
cat tmp2.txt oldbigfile.txt > newbigfile.txt
rm oldbigfile.txt
mv newbigfile.txt oldbigfile.txt
```

Note you need enough diskspace to hold both files for a while.

Comment: this solution needs a lots of free space on the disk since the OP says the files are very big.

Comment: You cannot avoid the need to temporarily store two copies of the data.

Comment: @sarathi if you say you can do content **append** without using temporary file (and without using customized filesystem and fs related tools), then I say - you do not know what you talk about :)