# Insert a few lines as the head of a huge file by emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs

For example, I have a huge file that I need to insert two lines before it. Is there a easy way to do it in emacs?

Comment: This is so vague! What are you really asking?  Are you saying you've tried to do this manually and the file is so terribly huge that your computer couldn't handle it - you want to know if there's any trick to make it work?  Do you want some emacs/lisp script to insert specific lines repeatedly?  Do you want to script up something to have emacs invoked from the command line and modify files like this?  What have you tried and what was the problem...?

Comment: tool agnostic: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file , sed version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368701/efficient-way-to-add-two-lines-at-the-beginning-of-a-very-large-file

Answer (score 7):

The only way to do that in Emacs is to visit the file, insert the two lines at the top of the associated buffer, and write the buffer to disk. But really, Emacs is the wrong tool for this job. You should do it on the command line instead.

One easy way to achieve that is simply using [`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat):

```
cat - /path/to/input-file >/path/to/output-file <<EOF
```

After that command, you can type your two lines right in the shell, and as the third line write `EOF`. This will then insert those two lines at the top of the file, and write the result to `output-file`. For instance:

```
cat - /path/to/huge-file >/path/to/output-file <<EOF
> This is the first line
> This is the second line
> EOF
```

If you have to do this for many files, it makes sense to write your two lines to a separate file, so you don't have to type them every single time. You would then simply do:

```
cat /path/to/two-line-file /path/to/huge-file >/path/to/output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

See also library [`header2.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/header2.el).  It lets you insert a file header (which you can define) automatically.